# I want to use an ODBC connection to insert multiple rows of data into the Hive table from asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hive, odbc, impala

I wrote the code below for multiple data insertion with 5 columns, but I need it for more than 100 columns with more than 1 million data and fast execution.

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
OdbcDataAdapter odbc = new OdbcDataAdapter();
cmd = Conn.CreateCommand();
List\<string\> ReadFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\\uc_Data.txt").ToList();
int i = 0;  
using (Conn)
{
Conn.Open();
string names = string.Empty;
string names1 = string.Empty;
int count = 0;
foreach (string customer in ReadFile)
{
var firstValue = ReadFile[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
var firstValue1 = ReadFile[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
var firstValue2 = ReadFile[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[2];
var firstValue3 = ReadFile[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[3];
var firstValue4 = ReadFile[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[4];`


if (count <= 250000)
{
names += "(" + firstValue + "," + "'" + firstValue1 + "'" + "," + firstValue2 + "," + "'" + firstValue3 + "'" + "," + "'" + firstValue4 + "')" + ",";

}
else if (count > 250000 & count <= 500000)
{
names1 += "(" + firstValue + "," + "'" + firstValue1 + "'" + "," + firstValue2 + "," + "'" + firstValue3 + "'" + "," + "'" + firstValue4 + "')" + ",";

count++;
i++;
}

swra.Stop();
ms1.Text = Convert.ToString((swra.ElapsedMilliseconds));
Stopwatch swra1 = new Stopwatch();
swra1.Start();
names = names.TrimEnd(',');
names1 = names1.TrimEnd(',');

var cmdText = "INSERT INTO TEST Values (" + names + ")";
var command = new OdbcCommand(cmdText, Conn);
command.CommandTimeout = 0;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmdText = "INSERT INTO TEST Values (" + names1 + ")";
command = new OdbcCommand(cmdText, Conn);
command.CommandTimeout = 0;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Need to optimise the above code; above, I create a string of data and a stored name variable, but the above code will not work for more than 100 columns. Can you please help me figure out why I can't store values and insert them into the Hive table?

Comment: Why was your question full of all sorts of formatting crap making it unreadable? Do you not look at what you post at all? The code is still missing indentation, please fix that.

Comment: Also, please don't use words like *lac* that are not globally used or understood